# How do I convert greyscale images represented as strings of space separated pixel values to column of features to train a classifier in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

data = pd.read_csv('fer2013.csv')
data.head()
```

[image: First 5 entries in training set]

```
face1 = np.fromstring(data['pixels'][0], dtype=int, sep=' ')
exp1 = np.zeros((48,48))
k = 0
for i in range(len(exp1)):
  for j in range(len(exp1[0])):
    exp1[i][j] = face1[k]
    k = k + 1
imgplot = plt.imshow(exp1, cmap="Greys_r")
plt.show()
mpimg.imsave('save.png', exp1)
```

[image: This is the image that i get]

The images are 48 x 48 pixels represented as a string ("12 34 12 34 55 ... "). So the first value in the string corresponds to the first pixel value.

Hence, my question is: How do I convert the string of space separated pixel values to columns of features that I can use to train an SVM classifier with and why is the image not greyscale??? The training part I can do for myself.

There are 35887 training examples denoting 7 different expressions so i need an efficient way of doing this.

P.S. The problem originated from attempting Challenges in Representation Learning: Facial Expression Recognition Challenge (Kaggle.com)

Comment: @tom thank you very much. Can you tell me how to get the image to appear in the post?

Comment: @tom i get it. Is it the exclamation marks?

Comment: Yes, but I think you need a certain amount of rep before you can do it

Comment: So is your problem just that when you save the image it is not greyscale? I think you just need to add `cmap='Greys_r'` to the imsave call. Or, call `plt.savefig` instead of (or after) `show`

Comment: that is one part. the other part is that I am unable to convert them to column of features which is what i need to train my classifier

Comment: and why not just: `exp1 = np.fromstring(data['pixels'][0], dtype=int, sep=' ').reshape(48, 48)`

Comment: Got it! working on it

Answer (score 2):

You should show current attempts/ research you've done already to solve the problem when positing questions on SO.

You can load an image in Python easily using OpenCV, the result `img` is a numpy array, so you can just print it as a string e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load image
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg',0)
print img
```

*Update after question revision:*

If you want to just convert the string of numbers to an image, you can use something like the following:

```
import numpy as np
image = '1 2 3 4 5 6'
image_width, image_height = 2, 3
result = np.fromstring(image, dtype=int, sep=" ").reshape((image_height, image_width))
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Hope the question is clear now. Kindly considering answering again.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

from sklearn import svm, metrics

#Read csv file
data = pd.read_csv('fer2013.csv')

#Number of samples
n_samples = len(data)
n_samples_train = 28709
n_samples_test = 3589
n_samples_validation = 3589

#Pixel width and height
w = 48
h = 48

#Separating labels and features respectively
y = data['emotion']
X = np.zeros((n_samples, w, h))
for i in range(n_samples):
    X[i] = np.fromstring(data['pixels'][i], dtype=int, sep=' ').reshape(w, h)

#Training set   
X_train = X[:n_samples_train].reshape(n_samples_train, -1)
y_train = y[:n_samples_train]

#Classifier
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, kernel='rbf', class_weight='balanced')

print('Training Classifier...')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Done!!!')


#Testing set
X_test = X[n_samples_train : (n_samples_train + n_samples_test)].reshape(n_samples_test, -1)   
y_test = y[n_samples_train : (n_samples_train + n_samples_test)]

#Prediction
expected = y_test
predicted = clf.predict(X_test)

#Results
print("Classification report for classifier %s:\n%s\n" % (clf, metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted)))
```

Here is my solution! Kindly let me know if certain things that can be done more efficiently. Thank you mark and tom for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

dataset_path = './fer2013/fer2013.csv'
image_size=(48,48)

def load_fer2013():
    data = pd.read_csv(dataset_path)
    pixels = data['pixels'].tolist()
    width, height = 48, 48
    faces = []
    for pixel_sequence in pixels:
        face = [int(pixel) for pixel in pixel_sequence.split(' ')]
        face = np.asarray(face).reshape(width, height)
        face = cv2.resize(face.astype('uint8'),image_size)
        faces.append(face.astype('float32'))
    faces = np.asarray(faces)
    faces = np.expand_dims(faces, -1)
    emotions = pd.get_dummies(data['emotion']).as_matrix()
    return faces, emotions

faces, emotions = load_fer2013()

xtrain, xtest,ytrain,ytest = train_test_split(faces, emotions,test_size=0.2,shuffle=True)
```

This code is very simple it loops over the the pixel rows in the csv file, return the int pixels separated by ' ' to face convert it to an np array then to an image with cv2 and stack all the faces in a list